# php < 5.3 garbage collection, do array values need to be set null or does setting the array = null orphan all its elements?

Tags: php, arrays, memory, garbage-collection

so I am using php 5.2 and needing some garbage collection since I am dealing with very limited resources and large data sets.

from my tests I have seen that unset does nothing until the end of the script(even if I run out of memory), which seems a little bit contrary to the documentation, although I assume that I am also reading the 5.3 docs not the 5.2 docs and the 5.3 docs seem relatively undocumented.

An barebones sample of my class is as follows:

```
class foo{
private $_var;

public function __construct(){
  $this->_var = array();
  for($i = 0; $i < 10000000000; $i++){
       $this->_var[rand(1, 100000)] = 'I am string '.$i.' in the array';
  }
}

  public function myGC(){
    $this->_var = null;
  }
}
```

in my function 'myGC()' should I do a foreach over the array and set each element I encounter to NULL (as I remember doing in C++) or would setting $this->_var = NULL free not only the pointer to the array but also all elements associated with the pointer?

Comment: How do you test your memory usage? Usually its ok to just dereference the allocated value. You should remember, that the gc is only called in intervalls.

Comment: I set a memory_get_usage() before the var was init, before it was destroyed to account for other vars using memory, and then after it was unset. memory grew constantly on each iteration that I tracked it, before and after unset matched until I triggered the out of memory error, then script execution halted abruptly. I should put an echo in my destruct method to verify that destruct ever was called.(I'm pretty sure it never was though, at least my mem logs lead me to believe that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's enough to set `$this->_var = NULL`, this frees the memory for everything `$this->_var` was set to.

You can test it with this (pseudo code)

```
echo 'before: '.memory_get_usage().'</br>';
$Test = foo();
echo 'after class instance: '.memory_get_usage().'</br>';
$Test = foo->myGC();
echo 'after unset of _var: '.memory_get_usage().'</br>';
$Test = NULL;
echo 'after unset of object: '.memory_get_usage().'</br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't call myGC() anywhere, is this the problem?

To test the assumption about unset not working, try running the below example. If it fails, your assumption is correct. If not - you have some other error.

```
class foo{
    private $_var;

    public function __construct(){
      $this->_var = array();
      for($i = 0; $i < 10000000000; $i++){
           $this->_var[$i] = 'I am string '.$i.' in the array';
           unset($this->_var[$i]);
      }
    }
}
$f=new foo();
```